# Обработка ajax загруженных изображений

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

Подскажите,как правильно навесить на загруженные картинки  draggable() и resizable()

```
$('img').draggable({
        containment: 'parent'
    });
```

Так не работает,может как то через **on**?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Для начала убедитесь что подключили библиотеку [jqueryui](https://jqueryui.com/),

потом попробуйте обернуть `img` в `div` и повесить `draggable` на `div`

Так же желательно делать селектор через класс или ID

```
<div class="wraper">
   <img />
</div>
```

И в конце повесить `draggable` на `div`

```
 $(".wraper").draggable();
```

Comment: Спасибо,разобрался,дело в том,что нужно было навешивать метод сразу же после ajax ,а я в другом месте это делал